# Show that the vertical component of the reaction is constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

A smooth wire in the shape of the helix $\vec{r} = a (\cos θ)\vec{i}+ a (\sin θ)\vec{j}+ cθ\vec{k}$, where $a$ and $c$ are positive constants is fixed with the $z$-axis pointing vertically downwards. A bead of mass $m$, free to slide along the wire, is released from rest
at the point A where $θ = 0$. Show that the vertical component of the reaction is constant.

I applied $\vec{f}=m\vec{a}$ to the particle vertically so I got

$$f=ma=R_{k}-mg=mc\ddot{\theta}$$
My textbooks solution is $R_{k}=mc\ddot{\theta}$

Is there anything wrong what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bead slides down a slope with a horizontal distance of 2πa and a vertical distance of 2πc.  The cosine from the vertical is c/a.  The acceleration down the slope is aα and the vertical component is cα. (α being the angular acceleration.)  Then taking + down, mg – R = mcα. Where R (the vertical component of the reaction force) is a constant (But it is not equal to mcα).

Comment: Thank you I mistook something